# Where to safely store Google Service Account .json file for Play Integrity API?

Tags: tomcat, google-play-services, java-server, on-premises-instances, google-play-integrity-api

Can the service account .json file be stored on the Android app side or the App server?

if on the app server, I am using an on-prem server. Is it safe to store here?

Thanks in advance.